# How do i remove this small gap on the edges of my layout in Android?

Tags: android

Here's a screen shot of my activity:
[I want to remove the gaps on the left and on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Om2z.png)

Here's my activity's xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hirewand.hudki.UploadResumeActivity"
android:background="#404040">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Your profile"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@id/actionBar">
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm adding the fragment into the placeholder dynamically. The height and width is set to match_parent, cant understand those gaps.

Comment: remove these paddings
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Remove those lines.

Comment: it could have been a comment @EpicPandaForce

Comment: i am here to help users to solve their issue and not for my votes; if the questioner really didn't understood the solution(say like if it needed explanation) then u could have answered.. again it depends on the individual.. :) @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake. Don't know how they crept in.

Comment: @DJphy Honestly, I made this into an answer primarily because I know this is generated code by the IDE, so it's easy to overlook it.

Comment: fine :) ... peace :D